# Animation of deleted item from list in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

A composable receives a list of items as status, that, through state hoisting, the user can remove any of these items to update the mutable state of the parent composable and this perform a children composable recomposition.

For instance: We can suppose that the items are for example a Text with a Icon in the right side. When the user taps on the icon, the item is removed and the status are updated in the parent composable trough a state hoisting. The code could be like this:

```
@Composable
fun parentComposable(){

   var listItems = remember { mutableStateList() )

   childrenComposable(
      listItems,
      onClick = { index ->
         listItems.removeAt(index)
      },
      ...
   )

}
```

After an item is deleted, and before the composition is done, I want to do an animation (fadeout for example), to make the item disappear. I've checked the built-in animation APIs to do this, but I think any of them fits with my goal.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/introduction

Any idea of how achieve that? I'm trying to make a delay after the onClick delete execution, but seems that is not working fine.

PD: The items of the list are not showing inside a LazyColumn/LazyRow. They are inside a FlowColumn/FlowRow.

Comment: How about you try animating the visibility of the item so you make it when you click the delete button launch a coroutine and inside of it animate the visibility of the item until it reaches 0f the delete it from the list

Comment: Inside a coroutine how? The animations in compose work as "wrappers" of the composables you want to animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is animating the visibility of each item when clicked, so you would have something like this and you change it to what suites you case best:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(list) { item ->
            val itemVisibility = remember {
                Animatable(1f)
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(30.dp)
                    .alpha(itemVisibility.value)
                    .clickable {
                        scope.launch {
                            itemVisibility.animateTo(targetValue = 0f, animationSpec = tween(20))
                            list.remove(item)
                        }
                    }) {

                Text(text = "item num: $item")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! I hadn't used Animatable before now. Thanks so much for this approach! I think it can be work. Do you have any idea of how implement any kind of "shrink horizontally" with this animatable? The idea is that when I delete any of the items, the next one comes to the position of the deleted one. 

I'll let you know if it worked soon. Thanks!

Comment: @adlagar if you find that this answer help with your question please accept it as the correct answer so that anyone with the some problem could find it easily

Comment: sure! I had to try it before voting :) thanks! do you have any idea of how I could do a "shrink horizontally" effect on the deleted item?

Comment: @adlagar specifically shrink horizontally no but you can do the  same thing that we did to visibility with Animatable to a modifier called scale but it will not shrink horizontally it wil just scale down